# How to substitute rows value by condition

Tags: r

I want to replace the values of some rows for particular column in the dataframe.

These should be the rows that contain the text that start from `ABC`. So, the thing is that there are rows with different values besides `ABC`, e.g. `ABC1234`, `ABC2376`, etc. I want to substitute all of them by `CDA`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

`gsub` can make sed like regex substitution (note that ^ means search at the beginning of the string):

```
df$column <- gsub("^ABC", "CDA", df$column)
```

Comment: @TTT123, maybe you should also add regex as a tag